# How to scale SVG path for anime.js motionpath function?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, anime.js

I am using anime.js to animate an SVG circle along an SVG path using the motionPath function. Everything is working except I am unable to scale the path. When I apply CSS style or wrap the path in a div, the visible path changes, but the function still uses the original path. Is there a way to scale the SVG path so that the anime.js function recognizes the scaled path.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 svg .corkShape{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#D4A676;}
 svg .corkTexture{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#CE976A;}
 svg .jar{opacity:0.3;fill:#30AFE2;enable-background:new;}
 svg .highlight{opacity:0.3;fill:#8ADFED;}
 svg .fireflyShape{fill:url(#firefly);}
 svg .firefly {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;}
 svg .square {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;}
 #jar-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
 }
 .fireflyContainer {
  top: 100px;
  left: 1px;
  position: absolute;
 }
 .trackContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top 10px;
 }
  .track {
    fill: none;
  }
</style>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Track-->
 <div class="trackContainer">
 <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="256" height="112" viewBox="0 0 38.37 68.86"><defs><style> </style></defs><path class="track" d="M-23.47-89.7c70.39-124,361.39,64.87,258.3,182.5-86.29,98.46-269.89-42.31-246.33,172C-4.9,324.9,22,421.63,85.33,448.6c81.9,34.92,123.69-45.7,118.31-115.21C191.63,178.3-113.26,68.56-23.47-89.7Z" transform="translate(40.49 130.8)"/></svg>
 
<!--Firefly-->

<div class="fireflyContainer">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200px" 
  viewBox="0 0 569 990.7"  xml:space="preserve">
 <radialgradient id="firefly" cx="137.9349" cy="1301.0017" r="68.1967" gradientTransform="matrix(0.8558 0 0 0.8512 4.3547 -551.9129)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
 <stop  offset="0.2659" style="stop-color:#00BBF2"/>
 <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#00BBF2;stop-opacity:0"/>
</radialgradient>
<ellipse class="fireflyShape" cx="122.4" cy="555.6" rx="58.2" ry="57.9"/>
 </svg>
 </div>

 </div>
<!--Jar-->
<div id="jar-container">
<svg version="1.1" id="jar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500px" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 569 990.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 569 990.7;" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Whole">
<g id="corkGroup">
 <path class="corkShape" d="M402.2,36.55H98.9A14.17,14.17,0,0,0,84.9,53l15.5,98.5a14.19,14.19,0,0,0,14,12H386.7a14.19,14.19,0,0,0,14-12L416.2,53A14.17,14.17,0,0,0,402.2,36.55Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
  <path class="corkTexture" d="M200.8,46c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm46.9,2.2c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.4-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm85.6,4.2c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-174.2,7.7c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.4-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm227.2,9.7c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-66,0c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-9.9,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,9.9,1.9,9.9,4.2Zm-66,1.3c0,1.6-3.1,2.9-7,2.9s-7-1.3-7-2.9,3.2-2.9,7-2.9,7,1.3,7,2.9Zm-66,6.7c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm107.5,10.1c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.8,10,4.2Zm-66.1,0c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.4-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.8,10,4.2Zm129.1,0c0,1.6-3.1,2.9-7,2.9s-7-1.3-7-2.9,3.2-2.9,7-2.9,7,1.2,7,2.9Zm-204.6,5.7c0,1.8-3.4,3.2-7.6,3.2s-7.6-1.4-7.6-3.2,3.4-3.2,7.6-3.2,7.6,1.5,7.6,3.2Zm242.2,9c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-142.1,3.7c0,2.3-4.4,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-67.8,0c0,1.9-3.6,3.4-8.2,3.4s-8.2-1.5-8.2-3.4,3.7-3.4,8.2-3.4,8.2,1.5,8.2,3.4Zm143.4,2.5c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.4-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-182,11.3c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-9.9,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,9.9,1.9,9.9,4.2Zm81.8,6.1c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.4-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm130.3,0c0,1.9-3.7,3.4-8.2,3.4s-8.2-1.5-8.2-3.4,3.7-3.5,8.2-3.5,8.2,1.6,8.2,3.5Zm-66,0c0,1.9-3.7,3.4-8.2,3.4s-8.2-1.5-8.2-3.4,3.7-3.5,8.2-3.5,8.2,1.6,8.2,3.5Zm-113.4,14.7c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm39.9,14.6c0,2.3-4.4,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-98.2-10.8c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.8,10,4.2Zm179,2.2c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm85.5,4.2c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-9.9-1.9-9.9-4.2,4.5-4.2,9.9-4.2c5.6,0,10,1.8,10,4.2Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
 <path class="corkTexture" d="M354,151.75c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm-38.9-1.9c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6ZM186,124.45c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm188,15.2c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm-240.8,3.6c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.7-4.8-3.6Zm126-43.3c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm73.5,27.6c0-.7.8-1.3,1.7-1.3s1.7.6,1.7,1.3-.8,1.3-1.7,1.3-1.7-.6-1.7-1.3Zm-46.2-77.4c0-2,2.2-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.7-4.8-3.6Zm-37,84.7c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.2,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm-16.4,9.8c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.7-4.8-3.6Zm45.2-28.8c0-1.4,1.5-2.5,3.4-2.5s3.4,1.1,3.4,2.5-1.5,2.5-3.4,2.5-3.4-1.1-3.4-2.5Zm101.6,5c0-1.5,1.6-2.7,3.6-2.7s3.6,1.2,3.6,2.7-1.6,2.7-3.6,2.7-3.6-1.2-3.6-2.7ZM107.2,96.75c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.2,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6ZM328.4,100c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6S338,98,338,100s-2.2,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm32.5,4.6c0-1.6,1.7-2.9,3.9-2.9s3.9,1.3,3.9,2.9-1.8,3-3.9,3-3.9-1.3-3.9-3Zm-68.8-6.7c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm92.3-12.4c0-1,1.1-1.8,2.4-1.8s2.4.8,2.4,1.8-1.1,1.8-2.4,1.8-2.4-.8-2.4-1.8ZM122,72.35c0-1.5,1.6-2.7,3.6-2.7s3.6,1.2,3.6,2.7-1.6,2.7-3.6,2.7-3.6-1.2-3.6-2.7Zm142,1.3c0-1.6,1.8-2.9,3.9-2.9s3.9,1.3,3.9,2.9-1.8,3-3.9,3-3.9-1.4-3.9-3ZM108,48.15c0-1.6,1.8-2.9,3.9-2.9s3.9,1.3,3.9,2.9-1.8,3-3.9,3-3.9-1.4-3.9-3Zm256.8,8.2c0-1.9,2.1-3.4,4.6-3.4s4.6,1.5,4.6,3.4-2.1,3.5-4.6,3.5-4.6-1.6-4.6-3.5Zm-27.6,7.9c0-3.1,3.4-5.7,7.6-5.7s7.6,2.6,7.6,5.7S349,70,344.8,70s-7.6-2.5-7.6-5.7Zm54.4,2.8c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm-190.2,35.7c0-2.7,2.9-4.9,6.5-4.9s6.5,2.2,6.5,4.9-2.9,4.9-6.5,4.9-6.5-2.2-6.5-4.9Zm2.3-42.7c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
</g>
 <path class="jar" d="M418.9,163.65c-.4-12.2,2.1-23.2,9.9-33.7h37.7a4.65,4.65,0,0,0,4.6-4.6V81a4.65,4.65,0,0,0-4.6-4.6H34.9A4.65,4.65,0,0,0,30.3,81v44.4a4.65,4.65,0,0,0,4.6,4.6H72.3c7.8,10.5,10.2,21.5,9.9,33.7C81,208,16.6,219.25,16.6,279.45v600.2c0,44.4,30.6,74.6,66.5,74.6H417.9c36,0,66.6-30.2,66.6-74.6V279.35C484.5,219.15,420.1,208,418.9,163.65Zm-295.7,681c0,15.1-11.6,27.3-25.9,27.3s-25.9-12.2-25.9-27.3V386.25c0-15,11.6-27.3,25.9-27.3s25.9,12.2,25.9,27.3Zm0-536.3c0,15.1-11.6,27.3-25.9,27.3s-25.9-12.2-25.9-27.3V302c0-15,11.6-27.3,25.9-27.3s25.9,12.2,25.9,27.3Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
<g id="jarHighlightGroup">
 <path class="highlight" d="M97.3,359c-14.3,0-25.9,12.3-25.9,27.3v458.4c0,15.1,11.6,27.3,25.9,27.3s25.9-12.2,25.9-27.3V386.25C123.2,371.15,111.6,359,97.3,359Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
 <path class="highlight" d="M97.3,274.65C83,274.65,71.4,287,71.4,302v6.4c0,15.1,11.6,27.3,25.9,27.3s25.9-12.2,25.9-27.3V302C123.2,286.85,111.6,274.65,97.3,274.65Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
 </div>
 

<script>
 
 var path = anime.path('path.track');
 
 var motionPath = anime({
  targets: ".fireflyContainer",
  duration: 10000,
  translateX: (path('x')),
  translateY: (path('y')),
  rotate: path('angle'),
  direction: 'normal',
  loop: true,
  easing: 'linear',
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll want to set up a working example. All you have to do is edit your post, hit Ctrl-M (or Command-M if you have a Mac), and copy the relevant parts of the code into the appropriate boxes. Which code goes into which boxes should be obvious, but comment if you need help.

Comment: You are using 2 SVG elements, each one with a different `viewBox` and different sizes, and you are moving one SVG element on the other's track. This is not how it is supposed to work. The usage is to have both the track and the firefly (in your case) in the same SVG element. And it can be done with javascript only or with SMIL animations (this second one with less browser support). Please let me know if you are interested in one of those 2 ways of doing it.

Comment: Hi @BobRodes, pushing command+m just minimizes my screen. I have a working codepen though - https://codepen.io/tessabanessa/pen/BvwbOo?editors=1010 Will this work?

Comment: @enxaneta - all the elements were originally in the same linked SVG but I couldn't get motion path to read the path of the line. I got an error of 'could return item gettotallength' So I brought the SVG code into the HTML. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean by the same svg element. One of them is a path and the other is a circle so they will always have to have different d='...' The animation is working; the issue is if I scale down the jar, I am unable to scale down the path too.

I'm brand new to all of this so forgive me if I'm misundertanding

Comment: I'm sorry, Tessa, I got it wrong. You have to use Ctrl-M whether you're in a Mac or not. You also have to be editing your post when you do it, and have the focus in the edit window. Works just about like codepen, and allows people to run your code directly from here rather than going to a link. Like in enxaneta's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using SMIL animation

This is how I would do it with SMIL animation. As you may see I've putted everything in the same `<svg>` element. Now everything scales together. Now the width of the svg element is `width="250"` but you can change this.

```css
svg .corkShape {
  fill: #d4a676;
}
svg .corkTexture {
  fill: #ce976a;
}
svg .jar {
  opacity: 0.3;
  fill: #30afe2;
}
svg .highlight {
  opacity: 0.3;
  fill: #8adfed;
}
svg .fireflyShape {
  fill: url(#firefly);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="jar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="250" viewBox="0 0 569 990.7">
  <defs>
    

  <radialgradient id="firefly"  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <stop  offset="0" stop-color="#00BBF2" stop-opacity="1"/>
    <stop  offset="1" stop-color="#00BBF2" stop-opacity="0"/>
  </radialgradient>

        <path class="track" id="track"
              d="M-23.47-89.7
                 c70.39-124,361.39,64.87,258.3,182.5
                 c-86.29,98.46-269.89-42.31-246.33,172
                 C-4.9,324.9,22,421.63,85.33,448.6
                 c81.9,34.92,123.69-45.7,118.31-115.21
                 C191.63,178.3-113.26,68.56-23.47-89.7Z" />
  
  </defs> 
  
  
  
<!--Jar-->  
<g id="Whole">
<g id="corkGroup">
    <path class="corkShape" d="M402.2,36.55H98.9A14.17,14.17,0,0,0,84.9,53l15.5,98.5a14.19,14.19,0,0,0,14,12H386.7a14.19,14.19,0,0,0,14-12L416.2,53A14.17,14.17,0,0,0,402.2,36.55Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
    <path class="corkTexture" d="M200.8,46c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm46.9,2.2c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.4-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm85.6,4.2c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-174.2,7.7c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.4-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm227.2,9.7c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-66,0c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-9.9,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,9.9,1.9,9.9,4.2Zm-66,1.3c0,1.6-3.1,2.9-7,2.9s-7-1.3-7-2.9,3.2-2.9,7-2.9,7,1.3,7,2.9Zm-66,6.7c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm107.5,10.1c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.8,10,4.2Zm-66.1,0c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.4-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.8,10,4.2Zm129.1,0c0,1.6-3.1,2.9-7,2.9s-7-1.3-7-2.9,3.2-2.9,7-2.9,7,1.2,7,2.9Zm-204.6,5.7c0,1.8-3.4,3.2-7.6,3.2s-7.6-1.4-7.6-3.2,3.4-3.2,7.6-3.2,7.6,1.5,7.6,3.2Zm242.2,9c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-142.1,3.7c0,2.3-4.4,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-67.8,0c0,1.9-3.6,3.4-8.2,3.4s-8.2-1.5-8.2-3.4,3.7-3.4,8.2-3.4,8.2,1.5,8.2,3.4Zm143.4,2.5c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.4-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-182,11.3c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-9.9,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,9.9,1.9,9.9,4.2Zm81.8,6.1c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.4-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm130.3,0c0,1.9-3.7,3.4-8.2,3.4s-8.2-1.5-8.2-3.4,3.7-3.5,8.2-3.5,8.2,1.6,8.2,3.5Zm-66,0c0,1.9-3.7,3.4-8.2,3.4s-8.2-1.5-8.2-3.4,3.7-3.5,8.2-3.5,8.2,1.6,8.2,3.5Zm-113.4,14.7c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm39.9,14.6c0,2.3-4.4,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-98.2-10.8c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.8,10,4.2Zm179,2.2c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm85.5,4.2c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-9.9-1.9-9.9-4.2,4.5-4.2,9.9-4.2c5.6,0,10,1.8,10,4.2Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
    <path class="corkTexture" d="M354,151.75c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm-38.9-1.9c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6ZM186,124.45c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm188,15.2c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm-240.8,3.6c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.7-4.8-3.6Zm126-43.3c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm73.5,27.6c0-.7.8-1.3,1.7-1.3s1.7.6,1.7,1.3-.8,1.3-1.7,1.3-1.7-.6-1.7-1.3Zm-46.2-77.4c0-2,2.2-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.7-4.8-3.6Zm-37,84.7c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.2,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm-16.4,9.8c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.7-4.8-3.6Zm45.2-28.8c0-1.4,1.5-2.5,3.4-2.5s3.4,1.1,3.4,2.5-1.5,2.5-3.4,2.5-3.4-1.1-3.4-2.5Zm101.6,5c0-1.5,1.6-2.7,3.6-2.7s3.6,1.2,3.6,2.7-1.6,2.7-3.6,2.7-3.6-1.2-3.6-2.7ZM107.2,96.75c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.2,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6ZM328.4,100c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6S338,98,338,100s-2.2,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm32.5,4.6c0-1.6,1.7-2.9,3.9-2.9s3.9,1.3,3.9,2.9-1.8,3-3.9,3-3.9-1.3-3.9-3Zm-68.8-6.7c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm92.3-12.4c0-1,1.1-1.8,2.4-1.8s2.4.8,2.4,1.8-1.1,1.8-2.4,1.8-2.4-.8-2.4-1.8ZM122,72.35c0-1.5,1.6-2.7,3.6-2.7s3.6,1.2,3.6,2.7-1.6,2.7-3.6,2.7-3.6-1.2-3.6-2.7Zm142,1.3c0-1.6,1.8-2.9,3.9-2.9s3.9,1.3,3.9,2.9-1.8,3-3.9,3-3.9-1.4-3.9-3ZM108,48.15c0-1.6,1.8-2.9,3.9-2.9s3.9,1.3,3.9,2.9-1.8,3-3.9,3-3.9-1.4-3.9-3Zm256.8,8.2c0-1.9,2.1-3.4,4.6-3.4s4.6,1.5,4.6,3.4-2.1,3.5-4.6,3.5-4.6-1.6-4.6-3.5Zm-27.6,7.9c0-3.1,3.4-5.7,7.6-5.7s7.6,2.6,7.6,5.7S349,70,344.8,70s-7.6-2.5-7.6-5.7Zm54.4,2.8c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm-190.2,35.7c0-2.7,2.9-4.9,6.5-4.9s6.5,2.2,6.5,4.9-2.9,4.9-6.5,4.9-6.5-2.2-6.5-4.9Zm2.3-42.7c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
</g>
<path class="jar" d="M418.9,163.65c-.4-12.2,2.1-23.2,9.9-33.7h37.7a4.65,4.65,0,0,0,4.6-4.6V81a4.65,4.65,0,0,0-4.6-4.6H34.9A4.65,4.65,0,0,0,30.3,81v44.4a4.65,4.65,0,0,0,4.6,4.6H72.3c7.8,10.5,10.2,21.5,9.9,33.7C81,208,16.6,219.25,16.6,279.45v600.2c0,44.4,30.6,74.6,66.5,74.6H417.9c36,0,66.6-30.2,66.6-74.6V279.35C484.5,219.15,420.1,208,418.9,163.65Zm-295.7,681c0,15.1-11.6,27.3-25.9,27.3s-25.9-12.2-25.9-27.3V386.25c0-15,11.6-27.3,25.9-27.3s25.9,12.2,25.9,27.3Zm0-536.3c0,15.1-11.6,27.3-25.9,27.3s-25.9-12.2-25.9-27.3V302c0-15,11.6-27.3,25.9-27.3s25.9,12.2,25.9,27.3Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
<g id="jarHighlightGroup">
<path class="highlight" d="M97.3,359c-14.3,0-25.9,12.3-25.9,27.3v458.4c0,15.1,11.6,27.3,25.9,27.3s25.9-12.2,25.9-27.3V386.25C123.2,371.15,111.6,359,97.3,359Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
<path class="highlight" d="M97.3,274.65C83,274.65,71.4,287,71.4,302v6.4c0,15.1,11.6,27.3,25.9,27.3s25.9-12.2,25.9-27.3V302C123.2,286.85,111.6,274.65,97.3,274.65Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
</g>
</g>
  
<!--Trackr   
<use xlink:href="#track" y="400" x="130" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" />--> 
  
<g transform="translate(130,400)">  
<ellipse class="fireflyShape" rx="58.2" ry="57.9">   
<animateMotion begin="0s" dur="10s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite">
<mpath xlink:href="#track"></mpath>
</animateMotion>
</ellipse>
</g>
</svg>
```

#### Using Javascript

The SVG part is almost the same with the difference that now I'm not using `animateMotion`. Also the CSS is the same. Please read the comments in the code.

```js
let track = document.getElementById("track"),
trackLength = track.getTotalLength(),
ff = document.querySelector("#ff"),

dur = 10000; //duration of one loop of track, in ms

function update(time) {
requestAnimationFrame(update);
var t = (time % dur)/dur, // position in repeat cycle 
distance, // distance along the path for the firefly
point; // SVGPoint for the distance 

distance = trackLength * ( t % 1 );//console.log(distance) 
point = track.getPointAtLength(distance);
   
ff.setAttributeNS(null,"transform",`translate( ${point.x}, ${point.y} )`);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
svg .corkShape {
  fill: #d4a676;
}
svg .corkTexture {
  fill: #ce976a;
}
svg .jar {
  opacity: 0.3;
  fill: #30afe2;
}
svg .highlight {
  opacity: 0.3;
  fill: #8adfed;
}
svg .fireflyShape {
  fill: url(#firefly);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="jar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="250px" viewBox="0 0 569 990.7">
  <defs>
    

  <radialgradient id="firefly"  cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" >
    <stop  offset="0" stop-color="#00BBF2" stop-opacity="1"/>
    <stop  offset="1" stop-color="#00BBF2" stop-opacity="0"/>
  </radialgradient>

        <path class="track" id="track"
              d="M-23.47-89.7
                 c70.39-124,361.39,64.87,258.3,182.5
                 c-86.29,98.46-269.89-42.31-246.33,172
                 C-4.9,324.9,22,421.63,85.33,448.6
                 c81.9,34.92,123.69-45.7,118.31-115.21
                 C191.63,178.3-113.26,68.56-23.47-89.7Z" />
  
  </defs> 
  
  
  
<!--Jar-->  
<g id="Whole">
<g id="corkGroup">
    <path class="corkShape" d="M402.2,36.55H98.9A14.17,14.17,0,0,0,84.9,53l15.5,98.5a14.19,14.19,0,0,0,14,12H386.7a14.19,14.19,0,0,0,14-12L416.2,53A14.17,14.17,0,0,0,402.2,36.55Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
    <path class="corkTexture" d="M200.8,46c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm46.9,2.2c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.4-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm85.6,4.2c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-174.2,7.7c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.4-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm227.2,9.7c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-66,0c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-9.9,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,9.9,1.9,9.9,4.2Zm-66,1.3c0,1.6-3.1,2.9-7,2.9s-7-1.3-7-2.9,3.2-2.9,7-2.9,7,1.3,7,2.9Zm-66,6.7c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm107.5,10.1c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.8,10,4.2Zm-66.1,0c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.4-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.8,10,4.2Zm129.1,0c0,1.6-3.1,2.9-7,2.9s-7-1.3-7-2.9,3.2-2.9,7-2.9,7,1.2,7,2.9Zm-204.6,5.7c0,1.8-3.4,3.2-7.6,3.2s-7.6-1.4-7.6-3.2,3.4-3.2,7.6-3.2,7.6,1.5,7.6,3.2Zm242.2,9c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-142.1,3.7c0,2.3-4.4,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-67.8,0c0,1.9-3.6,3.4-8.2,3.4s-8.2-1.5-8.2-3.4,3.7-3.4,8.2-3.4,8.2,1.5,8.2,3.4Zm143.4,2.5c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.4-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-182,11.3c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-9.9,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,9.9,1.9,9.9,4.2Zm81.8,6.1c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.4-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm130.3,0c0,1.9-3.7,3.4-8.2,3.4s-8.2-1.5-8.2-3.4,3.7-3.5,8.2-3.5,8.2,1.6,8.2,3.5Zm-66,0c0,1.9-3.7,3.4-8.2,3.4s-8.2-1.5-8.2-3.4,3.7-3.5,8.2-3.5,8.2,1.6,8.2,3.5Zm-113.4,14.7c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm39.9,14.6c0,2.3-4.4,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm-98.2-10.8c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.8,10,4.2Zm179,2.2c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-10-1.9-10-4.2,4.5-4.2,10-4.2,10,1.9,10,4.2Zm85.5,4.2c0,2.3-4.5,4.2-10,4.2s-9.9-1.9-9.9-4.2,4.5-4.2,9.9-4.2c5.6,0,10,1.8,10,4.2Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
    <path class="corkTexture" d="M354,151.75c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm-38.9-1.9c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6ZM186,124.45c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm188,15.2c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm-240.8,3.6c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.7-4.8-3.6Zm126-43.3c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm73.5,27.6c0-.7.8-1.3,1.7-1.3s1.7.6,1.7,1.3-.8,1.3-1.7,1.3-1.7-.6-1.7-1.3Zm-46.2-77.4c0-2,2.2-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.7-4.8-3.6Zm-37,84.7c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.2,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm-16.4,9.8c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.7-4.8-3.6Zm45.2-28.8c0-1.4,1.5-2.5,3.4-2.5s3.4,1.1,3.4,2.5-1.5,2.5-3.4,2.5-3.4-1.1-3.4-2.5Zm101.6,5c0-1.5,1.6-2.7,3.6-2.7s3.6,1.2,3.6,2.7-1.6,2.7-3.6,2.7-3.6-1.2-3.6-2.7ZM107.2,96.75c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.2,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6ZM328.4,100c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6S338,98,338,100s-2.2,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm32.5,4.6c0-1.6,1.7-2.9,3.9-2.9s3.9,1.3,3.9,2.9-1.8,3-3.9,3-3.9-1.3-3.9-3Zm-68.8-6.7c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm92.3-12.4c0-1,1.1-1.8,2.4-1.8s2.4.8,2.4,1.8-1.1,1.8-2.4,1.8-2.4-.8-2.4-1.8ZM122,72.35c0-1.5,1.6-2.7,3.6-2.7s3.6,1.2,3.6,2.7-1.6,2.7-3.6,2.7-3.6-1.2-3.6-2.7Zm142,1.3c0-1.6,1.8-2.9,3.9-2.9s3.9,1.3,3.9,2.9-1.8,3-3.9,3-3.9-1.4-3.9-3ZM108,48.15c0-1.6,1.8-2.9,3.9-2.9s3.9,1.3,3.9,2.9-1.8,3-3.9,3-3.9-1.4-3.9-3Zm256.8,8.2c0-1.9,2.1-3.4,4.6-3.4s4.6,1.5,4.6,3.4-2.1,3.5-4.6,3.5-4.6-1.6-4.6-3.5Zm-27.6,7.9c0-3.1,3.4-5.7,7.6-5.7s7.6,2.6,7.6,5.7S349,70,344.8,70s-7.6-2.5-7.6-5.7Zm54.4,2.8c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Zm-190.2,35.7c0-2.7,2.9-4.9,6.5-4.9s6.5,2.2,6.5,4.9-2.9,4.9-6.5,4.9-6.5-2.2-6.5-4.9Zm2.3-42.7c0-2,2.1-3.6,4.8-3.6s4.8,1.6,4.8,3.6-2.1,3.6-4.8,3.6-4.8-1.6-4.8-3.6Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
</g>
<path class="jar" d="M418.9,163.65c-.4-12.2,2.1-23.2,9.9-33.7h37.7a4.65,4.65,0,0,0,4.6-4.6V81a4.65,4.65,0,0,0-4.6-4.6H34.9A4.65,4.65,0,0,0,30.3,81v44.4a4.65,4.65,0,0,0,4.6,4.6H72.3c7.8,10.5,10.2,21.5,9.9,33.7C81,208,16.6,219.25,16.6,279.45v600.2c0,44.4,30.6,74.6,66.5,74.6H417.9c36,0,66.6-30.2,66.6-74.6V279.35C484.5,219.15,420.1,208,418.9,163.65Zm-295.7,681c0,15.1-11.6,27.3-25.9,27.3s-25.9-12.2-25.9-27.3V386.25c0-15,11.6-27.3,25.9-27.3s25.9,12.2,25.9,27.3Zm0-536.3c0,15.1-11.6,27.3-25.9,27.3s-25.9-12.2-25.9-27.3V302c0-15,11.6-27.3,25.9-27.3s25.9,12.2,25.9,27.3Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
<g id="jarHighlightGroup">
<path class="highlight" d="M97.3,359c-14.3,0-25.9,12.3-25.9,27.3v458.4c0,15.1,11.6,27.3,25.9,27.3s25.9-12.2,25.9-27.3V386.25C123.2,371.15,111.6,359,97.3,359Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
<path class="highlight" d="M97.3,274.65C83,274.65,71.4,287,71.4,302v6.4c0,15.1,11.6,27.3,25.9,27.3s25.9-12.2,25.9-27.3V302C123.2,286.85,111.6,274.65,97.3,274.65Z" transform="translate(-16.6 -36.55)"/>
</g>
</g>
  
<!--<use xlink:href="#track" y="400" x="130" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" />-->
  
<g transform="translate(130,400)">  
<ellipse class="fireflyShape" id="ff" rx="58.2" ry="57.9"></ellipse>
</g>
</svg>
```

I understand that you may want to use *anime.js* instead of SMIL or plain javascript. At least I hope you understand what I mean by "the same svg element". I hope it helps.

Comment: @enaneta - I've been playing around with the javascript version of the code you posted and I think I understand a lot better now. It's working great. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. I really appreciate it! Cheers.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful to you. In this case would you consider to accept my answer?

Comment: Oh sure, sorry. I didn't realize I could do that. I'm new to this site

Comment: @enxaneta  Valuable answer decisive question in two options